# Generating orderer genesis block for Raft returns unclear logs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Trying to generate genesis block for Raft by the following command

```
./configtxgen -profile SampleMultiNodeEtcdRaft -channelID testchannel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block
```

And in the output I see

```
2019-08-17 15:40:19.453 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2019-08-17 15:40:19.528 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
2019-08-17 15:40:19.529 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:20971520
2019-08-17 15:40:19.529 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: /Volumes/dr/hyperledger/testnetwork/configtx.yaml
2019-08-17 15:40:19.609 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 005 orderer type: solo
2019-08-17 15:40:19.609 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] LoadTopLevel -> INFO 006 Loaded configuration: /Volumes/dr/hyperledger/testnetwork/configtx.yaml
2019-08-17 15:40:19.612 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Generating genesis block
2019-08-17 15:40:19.613 CEST [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 008 Writing genesis block
```

As you can see step INFO 002 says it is raft orderer type, but then INFO 005 says it is solo.
Why it has two initializations and two different orderer types? Am I wrong somewhere?
I use configtx.yaml from first-network and didn't make any changes there.
V1_4_2 of hyperledger is used.

Answer (score 0):

Raft consensus protocol internally define solo orderer type only. So there isn't any problem with these logs. Its all working fine and you can continue further.